# paperjs - draw a line with arrows

Tags: paperjs

Im trying to draw a line with arrow using paperjs but it does not produce the desired output.

http://jsfiddle.net/1j6nLa7c/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    paper.install(window)
    paper.setup('myCanvas')



   x1 = 100;
   y1 = 100;
   r =  100;
   theta = .7;
   var path = new Path();
   path.strokeColor = 'black';
   var start = new Point(100, 100);
   path.moveTo(start);
   path.lineTo(x1+r*Math.cos(theta), y1+r*Math.sin(theta));

   path.simplify(300)
   var vector = path.getPointAt(path.length).subtract(path.getPointAt(path.length-25))
   var arrowVector = vector.normalize(18);
   var path2 = new Path({
      segments: [path.getPointAt(path.length) + arrowVector.rotate(145), path.getPointAt(path.length), path.getPointAt(path.length) + arrowVector.rotate(-145)],
      fillColor: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 6,
   });
   path2.scale(1.3);


})
```

Comment: As a side note, in your JSFiddle, JS comments use `//` at the beginning of a line of JavaScript, not `<!--` and `-->`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that creates an arrow. The object is initialized with mouse down point and draws an arrow with the tip at the point the mouse is dragged to.

```
function Arrow (mouseDownPoint) {
    this.start = mouseDownPoint;
    this.headLength = 20;
    this.tailLength = 9;
    this.headAngle = 35;
    this.tailAngle = 110
}

Arrow.prototype.draw = function (point) {
    var end = point;
    var arrowVec = this.start.subtract(end);

    // parameterize {headLength: 20, tailLength: 6, headAngle: 35, tailAngle: 110}
    // construct the arrow
    var arrowHead = arrowVec.normalize(this.headLength);
    var arrowTail = arrowHead.normalize(this.tailLength);

    var p3 = end;                  // arrow point

    var p2 = end.add(arrowHead.rotate(-this.headAngle));   // leading arrow edge angle
    var p4 = end.add(arrowHead.rotate(this.headAngle));    // ditto, other side

    var p1 = p2.add(arrowTail.rotate(this.tailAngle));     // trailing arrow edge angle
    var p5 = p4.add(arrowTail.rotate(-this.tailAngle));    // ditto

    // specify all but the last segment, closed does that
    this.path = new paper.Path(this.start, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
    this.path.closed = true;

    this.path.strokeWidth = 1
    this.path.strokColor = 'black'
    this.path.fillColor = 'black'

    return this.path
}
```

I like the tapered tail but you can get rid of that by fiddling with the constructor lengths.

Here's a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) with the mouse handling